# Smooth learning curve for DQN

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I create a DDQN agent, but I have some oscillations during the learning phase. I would like to know if it is possible to remove the 'inverse spikes' (=oscillations) of my curve attached? [Learning Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfpqt.png).

For info: I use a 3 ReLU hidden layers of 100 units each, as an optimizer I use Adam with a learning rate at 0.005 and the loss as MSE.

Thank you,

Comment: You need to describe the graph, I am assuming it is time on x and reward on y. If the question is, _how can I make my graph look nicer?_ If you are not already doing so, take a running average of the reward. Otherwise, training DDQN (or any variant) is inherently unstable - hence all the effort to stabilize it - target networks, experience replay etc. The instability can lead to these 'oscillations' in the reward. I am also curios as to why you want to remove them, you should really be seeking to understand them!

Comment: Also, if you are model is DDQN, your loss is not MSE and that is not your network architecture, please review this. For reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06461

Comment: Really thanks for your comments. Yes sorry I've forgotten to describe my curve: y = mean reward on the last 100 episodes and x = episodes. Yes it is a DDQN with only fully connected neural network as my problem deals with numerical figures. I've try to understand these spikes by changing lot of hyperparameters but no results.... I will try to use another optimizer... I keep you in touch about it.